# How do I use the BluetoothLEDevice.GattServicesChanged event?

Tags: bluetooth, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am developing a BLE app.

1. The "BluetoothLEDevice.GattServicesChanged" event handler return a
   "BluetoothLEDevice" object back; if this object is a newly discovered
   BluetoothLE device, does it contain new services?
2. What is Windows Phone behavior when the Gatt services are changed of a connected BLE device?
3. What are the differences if I am using "Generic Attribute - Service change" characteristics instead?

There are not very many documents outside about this, Hope I can get some help here!

Comment: I have edited your question. The first question in particular was very difficult to comprehend; you should review the change to make sure it still expresses the question you intended. As for the questions specifically: 1) this is an event on a specific device, so how could the device passed to the event handler be a "newly discovered device"? 2 & 3) What happens when you test those scenarios? It seems to me that these questions can be answered experimentally.

Comment: Hey @PeterDuniho windows phone will cache the device and services during pairing process, which mean later in code i will get old service return. I dont know whether the GattServicesChanged event will force windows phone to do a service rediscovering on the connected device. Another issue is during the Ble device having its service change, it will disconnect phone for some seconds, later it will use the same address to advertise. I am not sure if phone will automatically reconnect to the Ble device.

Comment: Those all sound like good questions...to be answered by testing those scenarios.